# apache commons-text StringSubstitutor, valueMap.put("amount", 20.0); how to output `$20.0`?

Tags: java, string-substitution, apache-commons-text

code:

```
Map<String, Number> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
valueMap.put("amount", 20.0);
valueMap.put("id", 123456);
StringSubstitutor ss = new StringSubstitutor(valueMap);
// I expect output: $123456===$20.0
System.out.println(ss.replace("${id}===${amount}"));  // output: 123456===20.0
System.out.println(ss.replace("$${id}===$${amount}"));// output: ${id}===${amount}
System.out.println(ss.replace("$$${id}===$$${amount}")); // output: $${id}===$${amount}
```

I expect output: `$123456===$20.0`, how to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting an escape char as shown in below example. I have tested it on my local machine and its working as expected:

```
Map<String, Number> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
valueMap.put("amount", 20.0);
valueMap.put("id", 123456);

StringSubstitutor ss = new StringSubstitutor(valueMap);
ss.setEscapeChar('\\');

System.out.println(ss.replace("$${id}===$${amount}"));  // output: $123456===$20.0
```

Please refer [java docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html)

Comment: `setEscapeChar('\\');` is working as the [default escape character is '$'](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html#line.248)